# Bash Shell Current Date Minus Number of Days

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, debian

I am new to bash and shell but I am running a debian install and I am trying to make a script which can find a date in the past without having to install any additional packages. From tutorials I have got to this stage:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# BACKUP DB TO S3
#

# VARIABLES
TYPE="DATABASE"
DAYS="30"

# GET CURRENT DATETIME
CURRENTDATE="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"

# GENERATE PAST DATE FROM DAYS CONTSTANT
OLDERDATE=`expr $CURRENTDATE - $DAYS'

# CALL PYTHON SCRIPT WITH OLDERDATE ARGUMENT
python script.py $OLDERDATE
```

Where I am getting stuck is the fact that my "days" is just the number 30 and isnt datetime formattted, so when I come to minus it from the currentdate variable it obviously isnt compatible.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me find a way to get this working as it should?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# BACKUP DB TO S3
#

# VARIABLES
TYPE="DATABASE"
DAYS="30"

# GET CURRENT DATETIME
CURRENTDATE="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"

# GENERATE PAST DATE FROM DAYS CONSTANT
OLDERDATE="$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "$DAYS days ago")"

# CALL PYTHON SCRIPT WITH OLDERDATE ARGUMENT
python script.py "$OLDERDATE"
```

See `info coreutils 'date invocation' | less +/28.7\ Relative\ items\ in\ date\ strings`

Answer (score 23):

Try

```
date -d '30 days ago'
```

should do on debian.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
days=73
while [ ${days} -ge 0 ]; do
    date -d "${days} days ago" +'%F'
    days=$((days-1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the python script instead -- that way you would not depend on particular implementation of `date`